# WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine (call Marketo SOAP API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice-client

I'm trying to call the Marketo SOAP Webservice
via ASP.NET / C#.
I successfully added the web service reference and tried to call it with this line of code:

```
SuccessGetLead lead = service.getLead(paramsgetlead);
```

The problem is I also get this exception:

> [WebException: The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine]
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) +263
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) +4
>
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) +172
>
> com.marketo.soap.MktMktowsApiService.getLead(ParamsGetLead paramsGetLead) in c:\Users\hubert.grininger\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\dynaweb2007\82e21235\d41bf12a\App_WebReferences.liqikruc.7.cs:206
>
> _test_marketo.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\workspace_c\dynaweb2007_test\marketo.aspx.cs:48
>
> System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
>
> System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
>
> System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
>
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627

I also tried adding

```
<system.net>
   <settings>
       <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true" />
   </settings>
</system.net>
```

but that didn't help either.

I think the request is never sent to *Marketo* but the error already occurs on my end.

Thanks for any help or hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. Problem was that the wsdl (provided by Marketo) wrongly pointed to localhost as webservice endpoint.
I programmatically set the URL via WebServiceObject.Url property and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

Just try to use HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1

look at the following code

```
objWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
```

It worked for me ;-)