# How to export to excel from a report on SSRS via ReportViewer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Maybe this question was asked already feel free to point me to the right direction if it is.

I have a report on SSRS and my Dataset/Datasource is there of course. The Dataset is a Dynamic Query.

The idea is to export the result of the report via Excel.

I have a web server control ReportViewer in my Aspx. Does anyone knows if there is a method to export to excel and how I can code it in my code behind.

Please let me know if you need more info and I will post it.

EDIT:
Checking the info and the other links I did the following Method.

```
private void CreateEXCEL(Dictionary<string, string> parametros, string nombreReporte)
    {
        // Variables
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty;
        string encoding = string.Empty;
        string extension = string.Empty;

        List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

        foreach (var d in parametros)
        {
            parameters.Add(new ReportParameter(d.Key, d.Value));
        }



        // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
        MyReportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = nombreReporte;

        MyReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(parameters);

        byte[] bytes = MyReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("EXCEL", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


        // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreReporte + "." + extension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
        Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download

    }
```

But when I execute my web app and call this method I have the following error:
The Server commited a protocol infraction `Section=ResponseStatusLine`

Did anyone come accross a problem like this?

Comment: This looks like what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241736/export-to-excel-using-reportviewer-built-in-feature

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Render` method:

- [LocalReport.Render](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251839%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [ServerReport.Render](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252214%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

The example provided by MSDN is for Excel but you can use the same method for PDF and any other supported formats.

Note that is also possible to manually export to Excel/PDF using the built-in functionality of `ReportViewer`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi buddy if your columns are dynamic in the dataset then there is no such optio n in SSRS. But I can give you a hint like when you edit and SSRS it would like XML.

Keeping that in mind you can construct the entire structure of the dataset as an RDLC file from your code.

> To be specific you need to generate RDLC file during runtime. Use the some common template and replace the template place holders with column value's

Personally I assure you it won't take much time to export the data. But you should put some effort to achieve this.
I'm telling this solution from my past experience. I have done something like this :)

Feel free to ask if you need more information. But don't ask code.

Answer (score 0):

> The Server commited a protocol infraction Section=ResponseStatusLine

Here's an answer that might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4289266/3854195